# Using laravel 5.6 Mail Facade, mail is sent but empty

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

The mail is sent but empty ! I am using laravel 5.6

***Function within SendMailController***

```
public function send_mail()
{
    $name = 'Hello';
    Mail::to('example@gmail.com')->send(new UsersRegistered($name));
    return 'mail sent';
}
```

Comment: i am using 5.6 there is difference between 5.1 and 5.6 . 5.6 uses Mailable Classes . laravel 5.1 method works well . I want to do it in 5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed send mail using `send(new MailerClass($args))` as you have done. Make sure that the class has a `build()` method, that returns a blade view.

Comment: A silly question, but does the view have any contents? Set the Mail driver to `log` and inspect it there.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending a blade or a body with your email.

Look at these examples :

```
    Mail::send('emails.welcome', ['key' => 'value'], function($message)
{
    $message->to('foo@example.com', 'John Smith')->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

One more :

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)

{
    $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');

$message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com');

$message->attach($pathToFile);
});
```

Comment: Your method works well its a laravel 5.1, 5.2 method but laravel 5.6 uses Mailable Classes https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail

Comment: ok, but you still need to have a body(view) with your mail or you will allways have an empty mail.